# Ext JS 4.1.3: How to get a value from a JSON store

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, extjs4

I have a `Ext.data.Store` filled with language variables. The JSON behind looks like this:

```
{
    "language":"en_GB",
    "data":[
        {"fieldName":"browserInfo","fieldValue":"Descriptive text"}
    ]
}
```

The store I have created:

```
 Ext.local.langStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
     autoLoad: true,
     fields: [
         {name: 'fieldName', type: 'string'},
         {name: 'fieldValue', type: 'string'},
     ],
     proxy: {
         type: 'ajax',
         url: 'en_GB.json',
         reader: {
             type: 'json',
             root: 'data'
         }
     }
 });
```

I'm trying to get the `fieldValue` from the given `fieldName`. How do I do this in Ext? I have tried using:

```
var getLabel = function(field_id) {
    var store = Ext.local.langStore;
    var index = store.findExact('fieldName',field_id);
    if(index >= 0) {
        return store.getAt(index).get('fieldValue'); 
    } else {
        return field_id;
    }
}
```

But have not had much luck with it. `index` is always `-1`

Any help appreciated,

Comment: What does `store.findExact('fieldName',field_id);` return?

Comment: It always return `-1` no matter if the `fieldName` is in it or not.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Can you try:
`var rec = this.store.query('fieldName', field_id).first();`
instead of using `findExact()`? Let me know what it returns.

Comment: `var rec = this.store.query('fieldName', field_id).first(); console.log(rec);` returns `undefined`

Comment: Hard-code the variable: `this.store.query('fieldName', 'browserInfo').first();` Also check whether the data is being loaded properly in the store via [`getCount`](http://localhost:8080/extjs/docs/index.html#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-getCount). Check that the URL `en_GB.json` returns the correct JSON as expected; should it be `/en_GB.json`?

Comment: The hard-coded variable returns `undefined` as well. But the store seems to not be loaded properly as `getCount` returns `0`. The URL is correct though, as it shows the entire JSON in FireBug.

Comment: Weird. In FireBug when I print the store: it shows as a store with 0 records, but when I click on it and open it in Illuminations, it has all the 660 records.

Comment: No idea about that. Myself I use Chrome's dev tools. But it *has* to be related to data not being loaded properly.

Comment: Solved it. There was no problem with the function it self, it was the testing procedure that was being called before the store itself was loaded. Adding a `Ext.onReady(function() { console.log(getLabel('browserInfo')); });` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented on the first post (re-posting to close this question):

> Solved it. There was no problem with the function it self, it was the
>   testing procedure that was being called before the store itself was
>   loaded. Adding a
>
> ```
>  Ext.onReady(function() { 
>       console.log(getLabel('browserInfo')); 
>  });
> ```
>
> solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var getLabel = function(field_id) {
    var store = Ext.local.langStore;
    var record = store.findRecord('fieldName', field_id);
    if(record) {
        return record.get('fieldValue'); 
    } else {
        return field_id;
    }
}
```